# What Java data type corresponds to the Oracle SQL data type NUMERIC/DECIMAL and get equivalent Java code for PLSQL?

Tags: java, oracle, transformation, type-conversion

I was looking for Java data type corresponding to the Oracle SQL data type NUMERIC/DECIMAL.

I got from web and other documents that java.math.BigDecimal is recommended for same. See one document.

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.doc.html

> The recommended Java mapping for the DECIMAL and NUMERIC types is
>   java.math.BigDecimal, a Java type that also expresses fixed-point
>   numbers with absolute precision. The java.math.BigDecimal type
>   provides math operations to allow BigDecimal types to be added,
>   subtracted, multiplied, and divided with other BigDecimal types, with
>   integer types, and with floating point types.
>
> The method recommended for retrieving DECIMAL and NUMERIC values is
>   ResultSet.getBigDecimal. JDBC also allows access to these SQL types as
>   simple Strings or arrays of char. Thus, Java programmers can use
>   getString to receive a DECIMAL or NUMERIC result. However, this makes
>   the common case where DECIMAL or NUMERIC are used for currency values
>   rather awkward, since it means that application writers have to
>   perform math on strings. It is also possible to retrieve these SQL
>   types as any of the Java numeric types.

My final aim to transform Oracle PLSQL logic into equivalent java code. I tried to explain with sample logic.

See example Below :

**In Oracle** :

```
DECLARE
    inv_quantity_Balance DECIMAL(10,2);
BEGIN

WHEN (inv_quantity_Balance <= 1) THEN
      inv_quantity_Balance := 2;
ELSE
      inv_quantity_Balance := 3;
END;
```

**Java :**

```
BigDecimal  inv_quantity_Balance  = null ;
if ((inv_quantity_Balance <= 1)) {
    inv_quantity_Balance = 2 ;
}else {
    inv_quantity_Balance = 3 ;
}
```

It shows complier error :

```
The operator <= is undefined for the argument type(s) BigDecimal, int
Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to BigDecimal
```

This is just one sample.
Please help me finding java equivalent for the same. How can I preserve precision and scale etc ?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's NUMERIC and DECIMAL can indeed be mapped to [`java.math.BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

The error you are getting has nothing to do with this mapping. It has to do with the fact that the operator `<=` is not defined for `BigDecimal`s. Comparisons are done with the [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo-java.math.BigDecimal-) method, like this:

```
BigDecimal balance = getSomeBigDecimal();
if (balance.compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) <= 0) { // lower or equals
    balance = BigDecimal.valueOf(2);
} else {
    balance = BigDecimal.valueOf(3);
}
```

Comment: The same for math operators like `+, -, /, *`: `add, multiply` etcetera. Ugly, but BigDecimal's correct precision outweights double with its impreciseness.